# Centos and Mercurial 1.7

Tags: mercurial, centos

I have setup a new Centos server and have installed mercurial.
However, the current release of mercurial on Centos is 1.6 and I require 1.7+ as I have repo's that have been created on a new version of Mercurial.

I am getting the following error when trying to access the copied repo:

requirement 'dotencode' not supported

I cannot remove this feature as it is being used.

Essentially I need to install the later version of mercurial but cannot find out how?

Anybody shed any light on this for me?

Kind regards
Col

Comment: Maybe try building your own RPM using the source code http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Download .  It's probably a bit of work but you might be able to get what you want.  It's never easy when yum doesn't have what you want.

Comment: What version of CentOS?

Comment: CentOS 6.6 - Sorry should have mentioned that.